# PHP processing Lavavel extremely slow, any clue?

Tags: php, laravel, macos

I've got a new project to maintain, which is based on Laravel 5.3. Today I set up my new dev environment on my **macOS** machine (installed **PHP** and **Apache** from homebrew), and found out that PHP processing is extremely slow. Page load takes 75 seconds, also running artisan commands takes minutes before any output. For instance "artisan optimize" takes over 5 minutes.

I did some testing, I thought the database is the problem. So I just shut down the mysql service, and again it takes just over 75 seconds for the page with the mysql exception to show up.

I really can't understand here what could be the problem.

**php -v**

```
PHP 7.1.33 (cli) (built: Oct 31 2020 00:01:16) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.1.33, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
```

**laravel.log is empty, no errors.**

**file/folder permissions are set to RW for everyone**

I also tried with php 7.0, the problem just persists.

I noticed something, when I run the project inside "htdocs" of a XAMPP with php 7.3 installation it is fast. The problem is that php 7.3 is not compatible with Laravel 5.3, but it's blazing fast to show the exception page.

So it seems the problem is just with php installed from homebrew.

Any clue about this?

Comment: "but it's blazing fast to show the exception page." That's likely because the request fails long before the long running feature of the application is ever called. I would start by examining all the Provider classes in `/app/Providers` folder. I'd suspect that one of those is doing some long running process. Beyond that gut feeling, you could use the [xdebug profiler](https://xdebug.org/docs/profiler) to pinpoint exactly what's taking all the time to process

Comment: First of all you can try putting a `die()` in your `public/index.php` to check how long it takes for the request to go from the browser through the webserver to your entry php page. Then you do the same for various checkpoints within your app. https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar might help for the latter part